# Extract different dynamic numbers in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have to extract 5 different dynamic values in Jmeter,four are always numbers while the other one is alpha-numerical as shown below with no boundaries (the response is as as shown)

```
Incharge 1  DL0413  1   6   1   1
```

I used **\t[0-9]\t[0-9]\t[0-9]\t[0-9]** & Template as **$0$** as a regular expression (in Regular Expression Extractor) to extract the four numbers, this highlights the numbers in the *View Results tree* when checked but I am unable to pass these in the following request.It passes all 4 numbers as one - 1611

Also used **DL[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]** to get the first alphanumeric data which has worked for me.
But I was looking for more robust extractor which could work for all the values

Comment: i do not understand your example. i see 6 fields. that is your input and how does your required match look like?

Comment: "Incharge\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)" should work.output will be \1=1, \2=DL0413, \3=1 till \6 which is 1 again

Comment: @vlad_tepesch **Incharge 1** is one identity which is not required but it is also dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Configure your regular expression extractor as follows:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, in my case it will be `test`
- Regular Expression: `Incharge\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)`

It'll match all the elements separated by tabulation as

[image: Regex tester]

If you add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to your test plan and look into it in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener you'll see that all match groups are there as JMeter Variables:

[image: Debug Sampler]

So you can refer:

1. First `1` as `${test_g1}`
2. `DL0413` as `${test_g2}`
3. Second `1` as `${test_g3}`
4. `6` as `${test_g4}`
5. etc.

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for more information on approaches of debugging a flaky JMeter script.